# Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code in flutter debug

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, debugging, ios-simulator

Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code, when debugging showing this , I build 3 apps first everything is worked after a week trying to debug showing this, when I tried a new app that's also can't debug

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was moving project dir to a folder which is not synchronized with iCloud. Try it! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with this same issue for about an hour today. Move your project files to a non-iCloud location.

Try placing them inside a directory underneath your User Directory. This immediately worked for me.

Hope it helps!